# Expresion regular para validar URL de google sheets

Tags: regex

Estoy usando un regex para validad que un input de html sea el URL de hojas de calculo de google.

*https:// docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID_DE_HOJA_DE_CÁLCULO/edit*

Estoy estoy basándome en  esta expresión   que encontré en una pregunta en ingles.

```
 /^((www\.)|(https:\/\/www\.)|(https:\/\/))?(docs\.google\.com\/spreadsheets\/d\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(\/(edit|view|export))?)$/
```

A mi entendimiento esta expresión cumple con la sintaxis de URL de las spreadsheets de google, y haciendo opcional poner la dirección completa con el protocolo y el www.

Sin embargo me devuelve como falso una URL valida de una hoja de calculo.

Alguien me podría orientar si hay una expresión mas adecuada para esto o hay algún error en la expresión que estoy usando.

Answer (score 2):

NOTA: *[a-zA-Z0-9_]* (que podría simplificarse con *\w*) no tiene en cuenta las vocales con tildes, como es en tu ejemplo con la palabra *"_CÁLCULO"*. Se podría corregir con *[\wÁÉÍÓÚ]*.

Si bien el código podría simplificarse:

```php
regex = /^(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?docs\.google\.com\/spreadsheets\/d\/\w+(?:\/edit|\/view|\/export)$/
```

> - **^** : se obliga a que sea el comienzo de un texto.
> - **(?:https://)?** / **(?:www.)?** : agrupación no capturada opcional.
> - **\w+** : conjunto de 1 o más caracteres de letras minúsculas, mayúsculas, dígitos y <_> (no incluye acentos).
> - **(?:/edit|/view|/export)** : agrupación no capturada de 3 opciones posibles.
> - **$** : se obliga a que sea el final de un texto.